# Save text/quote as an image fonts copyrights?

Tags: fonts, copyright, android

I have made a free Android app where you can write a poem, quote or any text and then save it as image and then you can share it where you want on the web. In my app you have the options to choose different fonts.

But I want to include fonts like Helvicta Nue, Consolas, and Arial, But as I have read, theese requires that you buy them for commercial(licens) use. But I already have them in my Windows system.

The licens isn't clear about using it in a free app where the font/text is then saved as an image. What is your say about my situation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a legal question which most designers won't be in a position to answer. Including fonts *within and application for distribution* is very different that the usage most designers fall under.

Answer (score 0):

That really depends what you mean. If you're using fonts that are already on the users' systems, then the user has a license to use the font and you have nothing to concern yourself with. If you are doing server-side rendering using fonts that are installed (or otherwise present) on the server, then you need a license that covers that use. That may or may not be considered "commercial use" regardless of whether or not people pay for the application. If you are distributing fonts to your users (including fonts in your app files *or* distributing the font for ordinary installation/use) for local rendering, then you need a license that allows you to redistribute the fonts.

Comment: No its just a simple Android app with no server or backend. The User can choose different fonts to write in and then save the text as an Image.  The user can not install or add other fonts.

The font .tff files are in a map in the android code.

Comment: @Elshaw - That's the **very first case** I addressed in the answer.

Comment: So does that mean that I can include theese font in my app?

Comment: It means that *you* aren't including anything; you're just allowing the user to access something they already have. And whether or not the font is properly licensed is the user's worry, not yours (they could presumably have an illicit version of a font installed, but *they* put it there, not you).